# Checking whether a fullscreen app has lost the focus to restore desktop screen resolution

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm interested in knowing how do "fullscreen" applications (the ones which change screen resolution to a certain value) **detect when they have lost the focus** and restore the desktop resolution. After then, how do they detect if they regain focus by maximizing and set it back to full screen?

Basically what I have:

```
LONG SetScreenRes(int cx,int cy)
{
    DEVMODE dm;

    dm.dmSize       = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    dm.dmPelsWidth  = cx;
    dm.dmPelsHeight = cy;
    dm.dmFields     = DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

    return ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, CDS_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

which works fine, but when I minimize the application, the resolution doesn't restore back to desktop one like in any other apps. Therefore I'm asking: how to detect this? Do the other apps just hook minimize/maximize messages or something? Or maybe something extremely simple?

Visual C++ (VS 2012), and it is a DLL (I am making an extension actually, does it matter?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, hooked WH_CALLWNDPROC and message WM_ACTIVATEAPP.